# Video compressed with ffmpeg is distorted when opened in cs6

Tags: cs6

I compressed output video from fraps with h264/aac with ffmpeg but this results in distorted video in adobe cs6.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Need more info. Full ffmpeg command and console output. And screenshots of before and after.

Comment: Thanks mulvya, im new to this and did not think to check against the console output.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by using the flag -pix_fmt yuv420p, for some reason the default pixel format is not supported in premiere pro cs6.